# SQL on Update attribute by joining two table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, database-design

Let's say I have two tables, and one table is the passenger, and another is the card.

```
create table passenger(
user_id char(20) not null unique,
name char(20),
age integer,
pin integer,
card_num char(20) unique,,
foreign key (card_num) references card);

create table card(
card_num char(20) primary key,
balance number(10,2),
cvn char(20) );
```

If I want to update the balance of the card of one passenger, how should the SQL written? Thank you very much.

Comment: What do YOU mean by "update the balance of the card of one passengaer?  Sample data and desired results would explain what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

For MySql you need to join the tables in the `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
update card c
inner join passenger p
on p.card_num = c.card_num
set c.balance = ?
where p.name = ?
```

and for Oracle:

```
update card c
set c.balance = ?
where c.card_num = (
  select p.card_num
  from passenger p
  where p.name = ?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Table "Card" should contain a foreign key referencing Passenger. PassengerId(in your case user_id) as foreign key.
Not the other way round

so your update statement would be like 
Update Card Set balance = value WHERE user_id= value;

Comment: The tables are related by card number, and card numbers are in 1:1 relationship with passengers. This is perfectly fine.